# Get flutter_service_worker.js being requested in My Django App, but I am not even using flutter in my web app

Tags: flutter, google-chrome

I don't why it is being requested. I have used flutter-web before, but this is an entirely new project.I have restarted the server I am still getting this error.This is my server log

```
22/Oct/2023 18:28:59] "GET /flutter_service_worker.js?v=3839392401 HTTP/1.1" 404 3871
[22/Oct/2023 18:29:01] "GET /?page= HTTP/1.1" 200 8646
[22/Oct/2023 18:29:02] "GET /?page= HTTP/1.1" 200 8646
[22/Oct/2023 18:29:02] "GET /?page= HTTP/1.1" 200 8646
[22/Oct/2023 18:29:02] "GET /?page= HTTP/1.1" 200 8646
[22/Oct/2023 18:29:02] "GET /?page= HTTP/1.1" 200 8646
Not Found: /flutter_service_worker.js
[22/Oct/2023 18:29:04] "GET /flutter_service_worker.js?v=3839392401 HTTP/1.1" 404 3871
```

How can remove this? I have noticed that it is happening in Chrome. Not in edge or firefox.

Comment: I'm getting this in firefox